# Asp.net: how to use jolly char against an integer field for a query in a datasource

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

Hy guys, my question is: if i have in asp.net, a SqlDatasource or AccessDatasource with the following select command: 
SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE SomeFieldID=@FilterID

SomefieldID is an integer

And i would like to use the jolly char (* or %) to show all datas... how can i do?

Thanks to everybody will help...

Bye
Stighy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a classic case of "when all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail". If you are trying to match "1%%" you actually mean >=100 and <=199. Similarly, when you try to match `SomeFieldID LIKE "*3"`, you actually meant `SomeFieldID % 10 = 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the LIKE statement?

```
SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE cast(SomeFieldID AS varchar(100)) LIKE '%' + @FilterID + '%'
```

This will return any record that contains the contents of FilterID.

Assuming FilterID is a string.